# Find the value of P[X>Y<Z>U] from a given joint distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, definite-integrals

Suppose the joint distribution is given by some function $f(x, y, z, u)$. Then find the value of $P[X>Y<Z>U]$ assuming that $f$ is non-zero only for $x > 0, y>0, z>0, u>0$

My approach: Simply integrate the joint distribution function, taking care of appropriate limits for all the possible cases.

**However, I keep getting some form of "*circular limits*" on the integral.**

For example, one arrangement of the values for $x, y, z, u$ can be $y < u < x < z$
and the integral looks like $\int_{0}^{z}\int_{u}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x, y, z, u)dx dy dz du$

Here, the limits for $z$ and $u$ are dependent on each other's value. Similarly for $x$ and $y$.

What is the way to deal with such integral limits? Forgive me if this a silly doubt, but I've been out of practice for a while. Please note that the RV are not independent.

Thanks

Comment: It is unusual to see a chain of inequalities with both less than or greater than in the same chain...generally this is avoided. At least one reason for this is that if the chain has all inequalities in the same direction, you get transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

For each integral you have to deal with (as you noted, there are several possible orderings of the variables), it may be easiest to integrate in order of the inequalities. So for instance in the one case mentioned in the original post ($y<u<x<z$), you could set up the integral as
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^z \int_0^x \int_0^u f(x,y,z,u) dy du dx dz$$

Or you could do $$\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty \int_u^\infty \int_x^\infty f(x,y,z,u) dzdxdudy$$

If you insist on the order $dxdydzdu$, I guess the integral would have to be
$$\int_0^\infty \int_u^\infty \int_0^u \int_u^z f(x,y,z,u) dxdydzdu$$
[Working from the outside, $u$ can be any positive real; $z>u$: $y<u$; $u<x<z$]

Comment: One observation: Why did you consider $y < u$? From the question, we know that $z$ has to be greater than $u$ and $y$ has to be smaller than $z$, thus, meaning that $u$ either lies between $y$ and $z$, or $u$ is smaller than $y$ (two separate cases). But even in the first case, if the value of $y$ is only considered till $u$,will it provide the correct answer?

Comment: I'm just not able to grasp why/if integrating only in the order of inequalities will be the correct approach. Any references or explanation will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You noted in your original post that there were several possible orderings (greater than/less than) of the variables. You gave $y<u<x<z$ as one possible ordering. As I noted in my answer, other cases would also need to be considered.  Also in my answer, I did give a way to integrate in order $dxdydzdu$, I just thought the other way was simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the integrals in alternate form to make the manipulations easier to see:
$$\begin{align}&P[X>Y<Z>U]\\[2ex]
&=P[Y<\min(X,Z),\ \ U<Z]\\[2ex]
&=\int_0^\infty dz \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^{\min(x,z)} dy \int_0^z du\, f(x,y,z,u)\\[2ex]
&=\int_0^\infty dz \left\{\int_0^z dx +\int_z^\infty dx\right\}\int_0^{\min(x,z)} dy \int_0^z du\, f(x,y,z,u)\\[2ex]
&=\left\{\int_0^\infty dz \int_0^z dx \int_0^x dy \int_0^z du\, + \int_0^\infty dz \int_z^\infty dx \int_0^z dy \int_0^z du\right\}\,f(x,y,z,u)\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$